# Is this an appropriate amount of "sliding yoke" visible on an 86 Dodge B250 / A727 Torqueflite transmission?

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, drive-shaft

Looking at my driveshaft tonight I noticed there seemed to a lot of yoke sticking out of the trans. (Recent rebuild)

Wondering if this looks right to someone experienced with this transmission/drivetrain (80s Dodge)

[image: back end of Torqueflite A727 Transmission showing sliding yoke and front u-joint]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's a bit too far out, however, let me pose a couple of questions:

- Are there any modifications to the truck? (ie: is it lifted)
- Does the driveshaft move at all in the up/down or left right directions?

If the answers to these two questions are "no", I'd suggest you've pretty much don't have much to worry about. The amount which is "clean" (well, cleaner than the rest) is about the travel amount I'd expect in normal usage. This is the area the seal keeps clean by the slight amount of friction and tranny fluid puts on the yoke when in use.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get the driveshaft to move at all, I was checking the U joints when I noticed this, I'd have been surprised if it was off since the shop at the put the new trans. in was experienced.

Comment: Oh and in terms of mods, there's nothing aftermarket, but it's a maxivan, the longest Dodge made, not sure if they stretched out the wheelspan a bit or just tacked more body on the back.

Comment: When the photo was taken were the rear wheels on the ground?

Comment: Yes on the ground, but not level, half on the curb so I could get under there.